# Kenmore 96573230 Dryer Heating Element Too Hot? (420° F)

Tags: dryer

Is it normal for the heating element metal cover to reach 420°F? 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/MnpC9.png

I just replaced the upper thermal cut-off fuse and it blew within minutes. The cover location of the cut-off fuse doesn't reach 420°F... closer to 200°F.

Comment: That sounds way hot to me is the vent exhaust blowing air? I would verify there is sufficient air flow across the coil to pushing air into the dryer, I have found the outlet plugged with lint and paper causing the thermal fuse to open.

Comment: All the airflow seems fine. All the coils glow in the heating element... I'm just worried somehow the element is running too hot for some reason. This temperature was after running it for about a couple minutes. Not long at all.

Comment: @FishBulbX - Were you evaluating the airflow when the dryer was pulled away from the wall and disconnected from the vent pipe? If so the point is that the vent pipe may be restricting airflow. If not cleaned on a regular basis this a common problem.

Comment: The flow seemed normal leaving the house, but yes, good point that I should be testing without the vent connected.

Comment: After further testing... seems like partially obstructed vent was the issue. I replaced the vent exhaust and the dryer is now operating correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After further testing... seems like partially obstructed vent was the issue. I replaced the vent exhaust and the dryer is now operating correctly.